# Unusual T-SQL - What is happening here?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

Can someone please explain to me what is going on with this query?

```
select 99.foo
```

It is behaving the same as

```
select 99 as foo
```

or

```
select foo = 99
```

Also, it only appears to work with integers.

Comment: Interesting; and SELECT $.foo will return 0.00

Comment: Also, SELECT 99foo gives the same result as 99.foo, but SELECT $foo gives an error.

Comment: Not sure why you say it only works with integers? `select 99.123foo` returns a column called `foo` with value `99.123` for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `select 99.foo` is translated as `select 99. as foo` (as you can leave out the space before the alias), selecting '99.' as a `numeric`. As there are no numbers after the decimal point, it just displays '99'.

You can confirm this by running:

```
select sql_variant_property(99., 'BaseType')
```

which returns `numeric`.

This is **not** the same as `select 99 as foo`, which does select '99', but as an `int`. This can be confirmed by runnning:

```
select sql_variant_property(99, 'BaseType')
```

which returns `int`.

Although all three queries appear to be the same, the first is different from the next two in the type of the value that is returned.

Answer (score 1):

The 'AS' is optional, so `select 99 foo` works.

The trailing period is interpreted as "point zero", so `select 99. foo` also works.

And there doesn't have to be a space between the value and the alias, so `select .99foo` works too.

These also work:

```
 select 99foo

 select 'ninetynine'foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write `SELECT col AS name` to have the `col` column returned with the name `name`. It is allowed to leave out the `AS`, meaning that `SELECT col name` is the same thing, but it's also allowed to leave out the space between them. In your example, `99.` is the number 99 and `foo` is the column name. In the `$.foo` example, `$.` is the literal for a `MONEY` value of 0, which is why it outputs `0.00`.

Answer (score 0):

The apparently confusing part is presumably the . after the 99, which makes it look like you're querying a field from belonging to an object called 99.

Just to really be weird, you can do

```
SELECT 99foo
```

and

```
SELECT 99AS foo
```

which both work (and give an int in a column called foo). Examples using . seem to return various numerics.
I'd say the parser's trying to be clever. If you meant the data to be one of the non-numeric field types then you'd be enclosing the data in apostrophes, therefore you meant something numeric. Therefore, anything that isn't a number is being used to deduce an alias.